# Joined object not available in self.play

Tags: apostrophe-cms

My widget joins an object with `joinByOne`, but the joined object is not available in `self.play` in `public/js/always.js` (only its id). It is available in `views/widget.html` though.

```
// index.js
{
  name: 'groups',
  type: 'array',
  schema: [
    name: 'buildings',
    type: 'array',                                 
    schema: [                                               
      {
        name: '_building',                              
        label: 'Building',                              
        type: 'joinByOne',                              
        withType: 'building',                           
        required: true,                                 
        filters: {                                      
          projection: {                               
            title:1,                                
            latitude:1,                             
            longitude:1,                            
            _url: 1                                 
          }                                           
        }                                               
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

In `views/widget.html` joined objects are available, as expected.

```
// views/widget.html
<div class="map" data-groups='{{ data.widget.groups | jsonAttribute({ single:true }) }}'></div>
```

In the browser console  `$('.map').data('groups')[0].buildings[0]._building` contains the joined object, as expected.

In `self.play` on the other hand, `data.groups[0].buildings[0]` contains the `builgindId` only, but no the actual `_building`.

```
// public/js/always.js
apos.define('map-widgets',{
  extend: 'apostrophe-widgets',
  construct: function(self,options) {
    self.play = function($widget,data,options) {
      console.log(data.groups[0].buildings[0])
    }
  }
})
```

This logs an object containing `buildingId` of the joined object, but no `_building`, i.e. the object itself.

It appears the join did not get executed in the object available in `data` in `self.play`. Is this on purpose?

How can I access the joined object in `self.play`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Joins are filtered out of `data` by default but you can override the filtering function per widget and essentially bypass the filtering.

In the `index.js` of your widgets module

```
construct: function(self, options) {
   // ... other stuff
   self.filterForDataAttribute = function (widget) { 
      return widget;
   };
}
```

Comment: A great answer — just a note that if you don't want really massive JSON in your pages, take a peek at how this looks in "view source" and decide if you want to trim some properties from a cloned copy of "widget" and return that.

Comment: (Massive JSON size is why we don't include joins by default. Also consider using `playerData: false` for any widgets that *don't* need a player.)